# How to convert timestamps to hive format in a pyspark dataframe?

Tags: python, pyspark

I have 2 columns of timestamps in a pyspark dataframe. How do i convert those timestamps as per hive table standards

| TimeStampA | TimeStampB |
| --- | --- |
| 2022:10:11:08:07:22 | 2022:10:11:08:07:22 |
| 2022:11:11:08:07:22 | 2022:10:11:08:07:22 |

Hive standards 2022-10-11 08:07:22
How do I do it dynamically.

Any ideas how to achieve it?

Comment: I suggest looking at strftime https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the `to_timestamp` function and pass the source [timestamp format](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html) to parse it.

```py
spark.sparkContext.parallelize([('2022:10:11:08:07:22', )]).toDF(['ts_str']). \
    withColumn('ts', func.to_timestamp('ts_str', 'yyyy:MM:dd:HH:mm:ss')). \
    show(truncate=False)

# +-------------------+-------------------+
# |ts_str             |ts                 |
# +-------------------+-------------------+
# |2022:10:11:08:07:22|2022-10-11 08:07:22|
# +-------------------+-------------------+
```